# PHP - when using foreach to loop through array, how can I tell if I'm on the last pair?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to 'pretty-print' out an array, using a syntax like:

```
$outString = "[";
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    // Do stuff with the key + value, putting the result in $outString.
    $outString .= ", ";
}
$outString .= "]";
```

However the obvious downside of this method is that it will show a "," at the end of the array print out, before the closing "]". Is there a good way using the $key=>$value syntax to detect if you're on the last pair in the array, or should I switch to a loop using `each()` instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Build up an array, and then use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$parts = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $parts[] = process($key, $value);
}

$outString = "[". implode(", ", $parts) . "]";
```

Comment: What does the `process()` function do?

Comment: Whatever you want... Sorry, probably should have named it more helpfully - that's the bit for the OP to fill in.

Answer (score 4):

You can just trim off the last ", " when for terminates by using substring.

```
$outString = "[";
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  // Do stuff with the key + value, putting the result in $outString.
  $outString .= ", ";
 }

 $outString = substr($outString,-2)."]";  //trim off last ", "
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the processing separately and then use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join:

```
$outArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $outArr[] = process($key, $value);
}
$outString = '[' . implode(', ', $outArr) . ']';
```

Comment: can you explain this answer?  This is interesting.

Comment: @Chris I left out the extra processing, but you can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join array elements.

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding the circumstances of your example (joining strings with commas, for which [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) is the right way to go about it), to answer your specific question, the canonical way to iterate through an array and check if you're on the last element is using [CachingIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.cachingiterator.php):

```
<?php
$array = array('k'=>'v', 'k1'=>'v1');

$iter = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
$out = '';
foreach ($iter as $key=>$value) {
    $out .= $value;

    // CachingIterator->hasNext() tells you if there is another
    // value after the current one.
    if ($iter->hasNext()) {
        $out .= ', ';
    }
}
echo $out;
```

Comment: Wow - I've never seen incomplete docs on the PHP site before - "Description here..." everywhere!

Comment: Yeah, some of the areas of the documentation haven't been fleshed out. I've been working with the DOMDocument stuff lately and it's similarly patchy. There's ancillary documentation for the SPL [here](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/), but it's not that much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to do it like this, and add a comma to the string before the item if it isn't the first item.

```
$first= true;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (! $first) {
        $outString .=', ';
    } else {
      $first = false;
    }

    //add stuff to $outString
}
```

Is the output format JSON? If so you could consider using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) instead.

Comment: although its not a big deal, to me this just adds complexity to the algorithm's efficiency when it does not need to be there.

Comment: Yes, but the approach is good too. It's easier to find if we're on the first element than the last. Useful algorithm which can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a normal for loop:

```
$outString = "[";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
   // Do stuff
   if ($i != count($arr) - 1) {
      $outString += ", ";
   }
 }
```

However, the nicest way to do it, IMHO, is storing all the components in an array, and then imploding:

```
 $outString = '[' . implode(', ', $arr) . ']';
```

implode() takes all elements in an array and puts them together in a string, separated by its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities. I think this is one of the simplest solutions:

```
$arr = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd', 4 => 'e', 5 => 'f', 6 => 'g');

echo '[', current($arr);
while ($n = next($arr)) echo ',', $n;
echo ']';
```

Outputs:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid using loops in situations such as these.  You should use implode() to join lists with a common deliminator and use array_map() to handle any processing on that array before the join.  Note the following implementations that should express the versatility of these functions.  Array map can take a string (name of a function) representing either a built-in function or user defined function (first 3 examples). You may pass it a function using create_function() or pass a lambda/anonymous function as the first parameter.

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// Using the user defined function
function fn ($n) { return $n * $n; }
printf('[%s]', implode(', ', array_map('fn', $a)));
// Outputs: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

// Using built in htmlentities (passing additional parameter
printf('[%s]', implode(', ', array_map( 'intval' , $a)));
// Outputs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// Using built in htmlentities (passing additional parameter
$b = array('"php"', '"&<>');
printf('[%s]', implode(', ', array_map( 'htmlentities' , $b, array_fill(0 , count($b) , ENT_QUOTES) )));
// Outputs: [&quot;php&quot;, &quot;&amp;&lt;&gt;]

// Using create_function <PHP 5
printf('[%s]', implode(', ', array_map(create_function('$n', 'return $n + $n;'), $a)));
// Outputs: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

// Using a lambda function (PHP 5.3.0+)
printf('[%s]', implode(', ', array_map(function($n) { return $n; }, $a)));
// Outputs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```